# Erro ao fazer multiple insert

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um formulário que gera múltiplos campos para adicionamento de dados, e depois envia todos os dados usando `for`, fazendo assim `multiple insert` na MYSQL. Contudo, estou com um problema.

Digamos que eu gere 30 formulários, desse total só está enviando 20, e os demais não estão sendo inseridos no banco de dados. Gostaria de saber se isso está sendo ocasionado por causa do tempo limite de execução de script no host, ou seria pelo fato do formulário estar muito grande.

Deixei abaixo a imagem do meu formulário, juntamente com o código original ao qual editei.

Código **`for`**:

```
for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++) {

Aqui fica o `INSERT` da minha MYSQL

}
```

Meu formulário: [clique aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrGI0.png)

Código original [clique aqui](http://cleartuts.blogspot.com/2015/06/multiple-insert-update-delete-crud.html)

Comment: o timeout é da requisição? vc criar 20 inserts ou faz um insert com multiplos values?

Comment: Sobre o timeout não sei lhe responder pois e hospedagem no hostigator plano normal sobre o método de insert editei a pergunta e deixei o código original para ter uma ideia de como e só que eu editei para o meu formulário adicionando mais campos.

Comment: Nenhum erro acontece? a tela fica em branco? o `ini_set('display_errors',true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` vc colocou?

Comment: Sim não acontece erro algum o que esta acontecendo e que a tela fica branca.

Comment: Coloca aquelas duas linhas no inicio da página, vai retornar algum erro.

Comment: Não apresentou erro algum ficou uma tela branca mais uma vez quando eu tentei adicionar 30 formulários. Só consigo adicionar no max 10, caso contrario fica tela branca ao enviar.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26267/discussion-between-rodrigo-and-rray).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já resolvi o problema era no caso limite de post_max_size que estava a 5m aumentei mexendo no php.ini e o problema foi solucionado.